# The android production build is getting failed in react native

Tags: react-native

The production build is getting failed while i'm tiring to build android suing react native

Its getting the following error

> Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2m 32s
36 actionable tasks: 31 executed, 5 up-to-date

I have tried:

cd android
gradlew assembleRelease